# Miscalculated width with padding in Chrome and IE?

Tags: css, padding

Staging page can be seen here: http://stevenacr.es/v10

When you click the menu button on the top left in Chrome and IE, the width of the `li` or `a` doesn't match what the menu items are, thus it's getting cut off. It works fine in Firefox, however. Very confusing, as when I open chrome's developer tools and disable/enable a CSS attribute with it (padding or the like), it properly resizes the surrounding `div` to fit the text...

Comment: try removing padding and margin from ol/ul

Comment: Is there a reason you don't have a width set on the #menu div?  Setting a width would resolve this handily.

Comment: @cale_b is right. lets give some value to ID `#menu` for example give a width 200px.

Comment: I was trying to keep it fluid, so it's just the width of the type within it. I have tried setting it as a percent, but when the browser is resized, it still cuts the words off. Take a look now, I've updated with a percentage width.

Comment: It fits now, but when you resize the browser the words stick out. I guess I could just control this with media queries...